# JQueryUi accordion overlapping page footer when accordion is expanded

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a JQueryUI accordion that is going below my footer when the accordion is expanded. Here is my screen shot.
[image: Footer issue]

Normally the footer stays at the bottom of the page but when the accordions are expanded they go below the footer line.

Here is the footer code

```
 <div id="divfooter">
        <div id="containerfooter">
            <div id="divfooter1" class="floatleft textleft">
                <h5 class="textwhite">Need Help ?</h5>
                <a href="http://support.somewhere.com/" target="_blank" class="textgrey">Browse the Knowledge Base</a>
                <br />
                <a href="http://users.com/downloads/Support/QuickSupport.exe" target="_blank" class="textgrey">Remote Support</a>
            </div>
            <div id="divfooter2" class="floatleft textleft">
                <h5 class="textwhite">Phone COUNTRY COUNTRY PHONE</h5>
                <a href="mailto:Please help me with the following problem:" class="textgrey">Email Support</a>
                <br />
                <a href="../Home/Contact" class="textgrey">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div id="divfooter3" class="floatleft textleft">
                <h5 class="textwhite">Licensing and Terms</h5>
                <a href="../Home/SubscriptionDetails" class="textgrey">Your Subscription details</a>
                <br />
                <a href="../Home/Terms" class="textgrey">Terms and Conditions</a>
            </div>
            <div id="divfooter4" class="floatleft textcenter textwhite">
                <h6>Copyright © 1998 -
                <script type="text/javascript">var d = new Date(); document.write(d.getFullYear()); </script>
                    . 
                    All Rights Reserved.</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
#divfooter
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:1080px;
height:120px;   /* Height of the footer */
background:#191814;
/*left:-0px;*/
}
#containerfooter
{
width: 1080px;
 margin: 0px auto;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is the scripts for the accordion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#accordion,#accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3 ").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: 0 });//active 0 makes the first div default to open


    // Hover states on the static widgets
    $("#dialog-link, #icons li").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
        }
    );
});
$(function () {
$("#subAccordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false }); 


// Hover states on the static widgets
$("#dialog-link, #icons li").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

My accordions are 4 accordions with the last having a sub-accordion. In other pages the footer is fine.  The page will simply push the footer down if there is more content than screen height. How can I get it to do this on the page with the accordions?

Comment: Can you post the code for the accordions?

Comment: Hi @apaul34208, The code for the accordions are the same as the code from here http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ I wont post it as they are huge

Comment: does the js look like this: `$(function() {$( "#accordion" ).accordion();});` ?

Comment: I posted it in the main section. I though you were asking for the jquery-1.9.0.js

Comment: Why not just remove position:absolute; from the footer? http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Y7yCJ/1/

Comment: Thanks @apaul34208 but Removing the position:absolute; makes the footer go "under" the accordion half way up the page

Comment: have you positioned the accordion? `position:absolute;`? Unless you've changed the css for the accordion it should remain within the regular document flow, so if you remove `position:absolute;` from the footer, everything should flow together.

Comment: Hi @apaul34208 I floated the div containing the accordions to the right but not absolute

Comment: float will also remove elements from the usual flow

Comment: Would it still affect it if I have a clear float?

Comment: @WillNZ Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the exact same issue but cannot find any resources online that are helpful